# Angular dynamic component circular depencency

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I am working on a dynamic component application [Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/gGMSeQ?p=preview) is the sample in plunker.
https://embed.plnkr.co/gGMSeQ/ everything is working but I have a circular dependency.

I have two types of components: `LeafComponent` and `ContainerComponent`.

#### This is my dependency *graph*

`AppComponent` `<--` `DynamicComponent` `<--` `LeafComponent`

`AppComponent` `<--` `DynamicComponent` `<--` `ContainerComponent` `<--` `DynamicComponent` `<--` `LeafComponent`

`AppComponent` `<--` `DynamicComponent` `<--` `ContainerComponent` `<--` `DynamicComponent` `<--` `ContainerComponent`

**`<--` means depends on.**

#### What I am trying to achieve

I need dynamically created leaf components in my root or in a container (which is created dynamically as well).

With this requirement, I am getting obviously a **circular dependency** when I **build with aot**.

This is because of the `entryComponents` definition

```
// dynamic-component.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'dynamic-component',
  // Reference to the components must be here 
  // in order to dynamically create them
  entryComponents: [LeafComponent, ContainerComponent], 
  template: `
    <div #dynamicComponentContainer></div>
  `,
})
```

and the fact that my `ContainerComponent` needs an anchor component in which we attach the dynamic children.

```
// container-component.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'container',
  template: `
    <div style="border: 1px solid green;">
    <dynamic-component [componentData]="componentData"></dynamic-component>
    <div>{{name}}</div>
    <div>
  `,
 })
```

#### My investigation

The **circular dependency** is just a Warning, yes! but it can lead to undefined behavior. This is why I am trying to see if there is a way to overcome this.

The angular team put circular dependency as a warning which might mean that it can be OK in some cases.

I couldn't find a way to put my dependency at a higher level because that will just push the dependency issue down in the chain.

#### The real question is

**How to solve circular dependency when you need it?**

Comment: You could use angular's `injector` directly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49240984/1160794

Comment: @David
I am using the `Injector` with all of my dynamic components already. Problem here is that I have `DynamicComponent` as part of the view so I don't think that can be injected.

Comment: Maybe try not to resolve the reference in the constructor, but just when you need it then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/entry-components):

> You specify an **entry component** by bootstrapping it in an **NgModule**,
>   or including it in a **routing definition**.

In your case, you specified entry components in @Component decorator

Updated your [code example](https://plnkr.co/edit/kV83h98UcwtcO7jOcOUK?p=preview)

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  entryComponents: [ LeafComponent, ContainerComponent], // Reference to the components must be here in order to dynamically create them
  declarations: [ App, LeafComponent, ContainerComponent, DynamicComponent],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```